# setInterval global var not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer:

```
 timer: function(duration, display) {
     var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

     var interval = setInterval(function() {
         minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
         seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

         minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
         seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

         display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
         display.addClass('timed sticky');

         if (--timer < 0) {
             $('.btn.next').click();
         }
     }, 1000);
 }
```

When I use `var interval = ...`, it works. But when I try to set it globally without `var`, it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: interval is not defined`. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you in strict mode? Then you need a `var interval;` declaration outside of the function.

Comment: @Barmar - yeah, that seems to be it. First time using React, so I guess that's a default thing

Answer (score 0):

Because you're running in strict mode.

```js
function strictMode() {
  'use strict';
  strictInterval = 1;
  console.log('strict mode');
}

function looseMode() {
  looseInterval = 1;
  console.log('loose mode');
}

looseMode();
strictMode();
```

Using that lack of `var` to create a global variable is a bad idea anyway. If you want to access a variable in multiple scopes, declare it outside of those scopes or provide a mechanism for sharing data between those scopes.

```js
// Declared outside of both scopes
var shared = 1;
function a() {
  console.log(shared);
  shared = 2;
}

function b() {
  console.log(shared);
  shared = 3;
}

a();
b();
a();
```